# Checking if viewWithTag exists before removingFromSuperview

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, cocoa, view, tags

Is it safe to use `[[self.view viewWithTag:999] removeFromSuperview];` without checking if the view actually exists?

There is no error on simulator but will it cause no problem on a real device?

Is there any drawback of not using such condition?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is completely alright to call `[[self.view viewWithTag:999] removeFromSuperview];` directly. If the view exists then `[self.view viewWithTag:999]` will return the view and it will be removed from its superview. If the view doesn't exists then `[self.view viewWithTag:999]` will return `nil` and **passing any *message* to *nil* wont take any effect**.

So, in your case, there is no need to check whether the view actually exists or not.

Answer (score 1):

Answer from the apple docs for UIView

> If the receiver’s superview is not nil, the superview releases the
>   receiver. If you plan to reuse a view, be sure to retain it before
>   calling this method and release it again later as appropriate.
>
> Never call this method from inside your view’s drawRect: method.

Nothing will happen when the view with the tag will return nil.